# Merging branch after adding submodule

Tags: git, github, merge, git-submodules

I have just added a git submodule to my master branch. I now want to merge that with my production branch. In my project root, all changes are committed:

```
git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

however, if I run `git checkout production` then I get a whole load of errors e.g.

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
        docs/themes/nativescript/_config.yaml
Please move or remove them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

These are all the files in my git submodule. How can I do the merge so they are present on my production branch?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more information, I'd say it seems like you have untracked changes in your submodule directory. Git is warning you that checking out a branch where that directory doesn't exist would clobber those changes.

if you navigate into that directory, and stash/clean/commit your changes in the submodule repository, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can just clone your repo again to a new folder. Checkout to the production branch (that doesn't have yet the submodule), and do a git merge origin/master. It would work now. Just push the changes.